# 403 error while trying to add reCatchpha to project

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use phone number login in firebase but I keep encountering an error when I try to add the recatchpha window. I get this error:

`message: "{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from referer http://localhost:5000/ are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from referer http://localhost:5000/ are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}"`

This is my code so far:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    render()

}

function render() {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
    recaptchaVerifier.render()
}
```

I have also tried to look at the apikey restrictions but that didn't work at all.